# Problem with ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a chart control in XAML, and  datapoints that are bind to the control.
The problem is when my ModelView changes the Collection of points the Chart control doesn’t get any notifications. I have tried dp, with ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged without any luck. I know that there is a difference between changing a field/property and making collection operations such as (add/remove/replace etc.) for the changes to propagate to the Chart control. But I haven’t got it to work. The change event is only triggered when I instance/reinstance the collection.

Does any have link to a working MVVM that works with collections?

Worth too know.

```
public class ObservableCollection : Collection, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

```
        public static DependencyProperty WorkModelsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WorkModels", typeof(ObservableCollection), typeof(Chart),
            new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection { }, new PropertyChangedCallback(
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                Debugger.Break(); //trigged only when collection got new instance
            })));

        public ObservableCollection WorkModels
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection)GetValue(WorkModelsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(WorkModelsProperty, value); }
        }
```

The binding is correct and tested.
Code in Window.Resources.

```
ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type vm:ListWorkViewModel}" x:Key="ListWorkViewModel"
```

The binding of control.

```
WorkModels="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListWorkViewModel}, Path=WorkModels}"
```

In the ViewModel I use the following code to rise changes. (When using INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
WorkModels.Add(workModel);
this.RaisePropertyChanged("WorkModels");

protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
     VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

When I use ObservableCollection I only add new data point to the collection.

```
WorkModels.Add(workModel);
```

[Question on MVVM pattern on WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422219)

Comment: Are you using a Visifire chart by any chance?

Comment: Does your WorkModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged or DependencyObject with DependencyProperties?

Comment: @Euphoric, It shouldn't need to. The only reason i can see for this not working is inside the Chart control. Perhapse put a breakpoint on it and see what it does when the property changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answers. I found the solution to the problem here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx

> For a dependency property in general, the implementation pattern that you follow is that you define a CLR property wrapper, where that property is backed by a DependencyProperty identifier rather than a field or other construct. You follow this same pattern when you implement a collection-type property. However, a collection-type property introduces some complexity to the pattern **whenever the type that is contained within the collection is itself a DependencyObject or Freezable derived class.**

Answer (score 0):

Needs more code. How do you bind? What type is ObservableCollection of? Are you sure you are notyfing in class that is value of ObservableColletion?

Edit: Also change title of your question. This is little ambiguous and not really problem of your question.

Comment: The Chart is a cutom WPF control.

Comment: The type of ObservableCollection is ObservableCollection<WorkModel>. 
WorkModel is the Model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this...

```
private IEnumerable<DataPoint> _DataPoints;
public IEnumerable<DataPoint> DataPoints
{
    get
    {
        return _DataPoints;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_DataPoints != value)
        {
            _DataPoints = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("DataPoints");
        }
    }
}
```

Then whenever you modify ANY point within the DataPoints collection, you raise a property change event for the entire DataPoints set

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        //this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Try changing the resource type from StaticResource to DynamicResource...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx#staticdynamic
The resource could be being loaded with the page/window and never updated. That would explain the lack of event communication

Comment: There is a difference between collection manipulation and changing collection data. Rising this.OnPropertyChanged("DataPoints") won't work when data is added/removed from collection.

Comment: This is true, but you just raise the same event when you add/remove just as you have done in your example

Comment: I don't raise anything when I use ObservableCollection. Please check updated question.

Comment: Correct. this is because ObservableCollection implements its own change events when you do. But if you were not using an ObservableCollection, but an IEnumerable (or other collection) such as in my example, you would have to raise the property changed event manually when you add/remove from the collection

Answer (score 0):

You've got this:

```
WorkModels="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListWorkViewModel}, Path=WorkModels}"
```

Why are you binding to a static resource? how is that resource defined? Is it in the XAML itself? Are you sure you're actually updating the same instance of the model  that the control is bound to?

Comment: Please check updated question for datasource.
The datasource instance is checked using a simple property (none collection type) that propagates to the Chart control.